# Use Freebusy to other calendar than 'primary'

Tags: python, api, google-calendar-api

I am creating events for a not primary calendar, I want to check if the user is not busy in this calendar, not in primary one for this event.

My query:

```
the_datetime = tz.localize(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 3, 0))
the_datetime2 = tz.localize(datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 4, 8))
body = {
        "timeMin": the_datetime.isoformat(),
        "timeMax": the_datetime2.isoformat(),
        "timeZone": 'US/Central',
        "items": [{"id": 'my.email@gmail.com'}]
       }
eventsResult = service.freebusy().query(body=body).execute()
```

It returns:

```
{'calendars': {'my.email@gmail.com': {'busy': []}},
 'kind': 'calendar#freeBusy',
 'timeMax': '2016-01-04T14:00:00.000Z',
 'timeMin': '2016-01-03T06:00:00.000Z'}
```

even if i have something created for that date in my X calendar, but when I create an event in primary calendar I have:

```
{'calendars': {'my.email@gmail.com': {'busy': [{'end': '2016-01-03T07:30:00-06:00',
     'start': '2016-01-03T06:30:00-06:00'}]}},
 'kind': 'calendar#freeBusy',
 'timeMax': '2016-01-04T14:00:00.000Z',
 'timeMin': '2016-01-03T06:00:00.000Z'}
```

Is there a way to tell the API the calendar I want to check?

Answer (score 3):

i found it! :D

in items of body, put calendar id instead of mail